# Converting SQL query to LINQ format - SQL

Tags: sql, linq, join

I have this sql query that needs to be in linq. I'm really new to it so I still cant figure out how to use it.

```
SELECT a.Fecha, a.ContratoId, a.TotalContrato, a.Plazo, a.ValorCuota, a.Fecha_de_vencimiento 
FROM Contrato AS a LEFT JOIN Contrato_detalle AS b ON a.ContratoId = b.ContratoId 
AND a.ContratoId < b.ContratoId 
Left join Contrato_plan_pagos c on a.ContratoId = c.ContratoId 
And a.ContratoId < b.ContratoId
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var resultsQueryable = from a in Contrato
                       join b in Contrato_detalle on a.ContratoId equals b.ContratoId into abGroup
                       from ab in abGroup where a.ContratoId < ab.ContratoId
                       join c in Contrato_plan_pagos on a.ContratoId equals c.ContratoId into acGroup
                       from ac in acGroup where ContratoId < c.ContratoId
                       select new {
                              a.Fecha,
                              a.ContratoId,
                              a.TotalContrato,
                              a.Plazo,
                              a.ValorCuota,
                              a.Fecha_de_vencimiento
                       };
var results = resultsQueryable.ToList();
```

or

```
var resultsQueryable = Contrato.GroupJoin(Contrato_detalle,
                    a => a.ContratoId, b => b.ContratoId, (a, comp) => new {v = a, comp})
                .SelectMany(x => x.comp, (t1, b) => new { a = t1.v, b = b })
                .Where(abGroup => abGroup.a.id < abGroup.b.id)
                .GroupJoin(Contrato_plan_pagos, t => t.b.ContratoId, c => c.ContratoId, (t, grp) => new {t, grp})
                .SelectMany(t => t.grp, (t, c) => new {a = t.t.a, b = t.t.b, c = c})
                .Where(acGroup => acGroup.a.id < acGroup.c.id)
                .Select(x => new {
                                    a.Fecha,
                                    a.ContratoId,
                                    a.TotalContrato,
                                    a.Plazo,
                                    a.ValorCuota,
                                    a.Fecha_de_vencimiento
                                });
var results = resultsQueryable.ToList();
```

**UPDATE**:
Since you need to return just Contrato properties, you can further simplify your linq as shown below:

```
var resultsQueryable = from a in Contrato
                       join b in Contrato_detalle on a.ContratoId equals b.ContratoId
                       join c in Contrato_plan_pagos on a.ContratoId equals c.ContratoId
                       where a.ContratoId < b.ContratoId and a.ContratoId < c.ContratoId
                       select new {
                              a.Fecha,
                              a.ContratoId,
                              a.TotalContrato,
                              a.Plazo,
                              a.ValorCuota,
                              a.Fecha_de_vencimiento
                       };
var results = resultsQueryable.ToList();
```

Comment: Writing people's code for them does not encourage them to learn how to write it themselves, and as such this type of answer is discouraged. Questions where the asker shows no attempt to write the code themselves add nothing to the site, and as such are discouraged from being answered. Please don't waste your own valuable time doing someone else's work for them.

Comment: @IanKemp thanks for letting me know. I saw many other StackOverflow posts where people have provided answers like these. For example, please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571670/calculate-average-age-of-persons-with-a-sql-query and there are many other more.